# undo changes in submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to create a PR in a repo which have sub modules.

I compared my branch and develop branch and I see that the hash for 1 submodule has changed (which wasn't part of the PR).

How can I bring the submodule to the version in develop so the changes won't appear in the PR?

Comment: Check out the correct commit in the submodule, and either commit it as a fix-up commit on top of your branch, or you rewrite the history of your branch to never have changed the submodule reference to begin with.

Comment: thank you - it worked